# size arrays varying over loop

Tags: python, arrays

I need to plot vertical lines on top of time series. The values of these lines are determined by array positions, which are always the same. As an example, the on_ofProc[j][0][0] element exists for all **j**, however the element on_ofProc[j][1][0] does not. When I try to run the code, it is of course complaining with an "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1" when the array position [j][1][0] does not exists.

Any idea on how to deal with it?
Many thanks!

```
   for j in range(len(x)):
      plt.figure(figsize=(18,7))#
      ax = plt.subplot(211)
      plt.plot(tracesProc[j], 'k')
      ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
      if on_ofProc[j] != []:    
          plt.vlines(on_ofProc[j][0][0], ymin, ymax, color='r', linewidth=2)
          ##here is the problem##
          plt.vlines(on_ofProc[j][1][0], ymin, ymax, color='r', linewidth=3)
          ##here is the problem##
      if on_ofNonP[j] != []:
          plt.vlines(on_ofNonP[j][0][0], ymin, ymax, color='m', linewidth=2)
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you try to use index 1 if you already know that the array only has size 1 (and therefore only index 0 is valid)?

Comment: It is because for some values of j I have this: [[207 221]]
and for others this: [[209 224]
                                 [505 511]]
Then for the first case I just have the [j][0][0] or the [j][0][1] options, but for the other cases it is possible to read additionally  [j][1][0] or  [j][1][1]. 
And this is what I can not do, as not all the arrays have the same size for different j values :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but ...

Does the code below do the trick ?

```
if len(on_ofProc[j]) > 1:
    plt.vlines(on_ofProc[j][1][0], ymin, ymax, color='r', linewidth=3)
```